# Pytesseract splits between line

Tags: python, python-tesseract

i have a problem with pytesseract.
On some jpg the output lines are splitted.
Here is the jpg example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2YPL.jpg)
JPG

And here is the Output from pytesseract:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQt84.png)
Output

It splits the Numbers in a diffrent row.
Does anyone know how to fix this?
Im sorry for this poor post but Im in a hurry.
Thanking anyone who tries to help me.

Comment: I think your expectations may be unrealistic.  It's a miracle that it's able to get as much as it does.  However, Tesseract does have several operating modes.  You may need to use the `config` parameter to set the  `--psm` option to the Tesseract app.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.